# Error in using profiling object is not callable

Tags: python

I am trying to to use the pandas profiling for profile report. I got the error "module' object is not callable. How can I fix in Jupyter notebook from Anaconda.

My code:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_profiling
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\tai.phan\Desktop\Pythone training\Data\titanic.csv')
pandas_profiling.profile_report(df)
```

The error:

```
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Comment: what line are you receiving the error on?

Comment: Like it says, `pandas_profiling.profile_report` [is a module](https://pandas-profiling.github.io/pandas-profiling/docs/master/profile_report.html). You need to read the documentation and then figure out what you want to do with that module. For example, you might create an instance of the `pandas_profiling.profile_report.ProfileReport` class, and then use its methods.

Comment: @toRex your suggestion makes no sense, and it comes across as though you searched for a duplicate and then tried to copy the advice from there.

Answer (score 0):

pandas_profiling isn't a function

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_profiling.profile_report as report
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\tai.phan\Desktop\Pythone training\Data\titanic.csv')
report.whateverfunctionyouwant(df)
```

look at the documentation to understand this module more

- https://pandas-profiling.github.io/pandas-profiling/docs/master/index.html

you can also select a function from the following list of functions for profile_report

- clear_config
- description_set
- df_hash
- get_description
- get_duplicates
- get_rejected_variables
- get_sample
- html
- json
- preprocess
- report
- set_variable
- set_variables
- title
- to_app
- to_file
- to_html
- to_json
- to_notebook_iframe
- to_widgets
- widgets

Comment: I am new in python. can you be exactly what you meant  "report.whateverfunctionyouwant(df)

Answer (score 0):

try `df.profile_report()` worked for me

Answer (score -1):

```
import pandas_profiling

df.profile_report()
```

The above is working for me

Comment: Please don't repeat answers.